# "Argument not Optional error" when running a sub with the right arguments

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new to vba and i'm having a not optional argument error while executing a subroutine in vba to hide rows that have some cells with the same color

i tried passing a variable instead of the raw string

my sub

```
Public Sub Ocultar_Campos_Monetarios(MarkedCells As String)
    If Range("" & MarkedCells & "").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "*"
   Range.Rows(Range("" & MarkedCells & "").Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Range.Rows(Range("" & MarkedCells & "").Row - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect "*", AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

the call:

```
call Ocultar_Campos_Monetarios("D19,L19,T19")
```

Comment: You can't do `Range.Rows`.

Comment: Also the 2nd `.Unprotect` looks like it wants to be `.Protect`

Comment: Also, all your Range Calls are implicitely referring to the activeSheet (which in this case may actually be intended) Here's a good read up on it: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/clean-vba-code-pt-2-avoiding-implicit-code/ A clean way is to dim/set a worksheet object to the worksheet you want to use (even if it is the active Worksheet) at the beginning of the code/block. This prevents errors when someone changes the worksheet during execution or you need to run the code for a different sheet. Example: `Dim sht as Excel.Worksheet` and `Set sht = ActiveSheet`

Comment: Thank you all guys, i'm going to correct those mistakes and try to implement what @l8n said in my code